# In Azure How to create a VM from Image in different region?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is it possible to create a new VM from Image in different region ?

What I did is captured an image from my VM which is hosted in North Europe and try to create a new one with this image in West Europe but I didn't find any other regions in the list!!

[image]

Is there a way to do this smoothly ?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Thanks Marcus , in fact I found a lot of questions similar to mine in Stack Overflow , why it is not off-topic though?

Comment: The others are off-topic, too, in my humble opinion. If your question is about programming, SO is the right place. If your question is about setting up software that you want to use (not explicitly use for programming), it's an administration question, and off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to create the vm in the same region where the image resides.

VM is created from image. If image itself is not there as a form of disc in any specific region there comes no point of creating a vm with that image in some different region.